# How to use System.out.printf() to display output of number to only two decimal places?

Tags: java

I am creating my first java program for the class. The purpose of the program is to calculate `interest` for `deposit` for year one and year two. My issue comes when the code outputs the final totals. The last two lines are supposed to use `System.out.printf()`. I keep getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'`. How do I correct this?

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello World!");

    //declares variables
    double interest = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    double deposit = 0;
    double secondYearBalance = 0;
    double secondYearInterest = 0;

    //displays welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to George's Interest Calculator");

    //prompts user for input
    System.out.println("Please enter your initial deposit:");
    deposit = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Finds outs interest interest earned on deposit
    interest = deposit * TAXRATE;

    //Finds out the amount of the balance
    balance = deposit + interest;

    //finds out second year balance
    secondYearInterest = balance * TAXRATE;
    secondYearBalance = secondYearInterest + balance;

    //Outputs totals
    System.out.printf("Your balance after one year with a 4.9% interest rate is $%7.2f %n", balance);
    System.out.printf("Your balance after two years with a 4.9% interest rate is $%7.2f %n", secondYearBalance);

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` symbol is used in a printf string for 'put a variable here'.

That's problematic when you write `4.9% interest rate` because java thinks that `% i` is you saying: "a variable goes here". The fix is trivial; a double % is how you write a single percent. Thus:

```
System.out.printf("Your balance after one year with a 4.9%% interest rate is $%7.2f %n", balance);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the explanation.